# Login Screen in MVC 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I am very much new to ASP.NET MVC 2.

I am trying to make simple login screen from [Custom Login Screen](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/482546/Creating-a-custom-user-login-form-with-NET-Csharp)  (The tutorial is in MVC 4)

This is my Login View and the rest Model and controller is same as described in the Linked example.

```
 <div class="editor-label">
            <%=Html.LabelFor(u => u.UserName)%>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%=Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.UserName)%>
            <%=Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.UserName)%>
        </div>

  <input type="submit" value="Log In" />
```

How can i link it with Model and controller ?

Please help

Comment: I think the Solution already has a `BeginForm()`. So what exactly is your problem? It should work as it is given in the  solution link you provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the answer given by Bios

in the first method any button with type `submit` will call the action defined in the

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", null, FormMethod.Post, new {@id = "value")) {%>
```

same goes for `<form method="post" action="/Controller/Action">`

Answer (score 1):

If your using a **razor** as view engine try **Html.BeginForm()** for form submission.

Example:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", null, FormMethod.Post, new {@id = "value")) {%>

 //Your form goes here

<% } %>
```

Or

```
<form method="post" action="/Controller/Action">
   //Your form goes here
</form>
```